# How do I make variable weights dynamic in lmer for loop

Tags: r, lme4

I want to be able to input the variable name that I'll be using in the "weights" option in the lmer function. So then I can change the dataset, and cycle through the "weights" and pull the correct variable.

I want to pull the correct column for weights within the for loop.
So for y, the equation would be:
lmer(y~x+(1|study), weights = weight.var)
And y1:
lmer(y1~x+(1|study),weights = weight.var1)
So I named the weighting variables (weight.opt), then want to use them in the formula within the for loop. I can use "as.formula" to get the formula working and connected to the dataset, but I'm not sure how to do something similar with the weights.

```
x <- rnorm(300,0,1)
y <- x*rnorm(300,2,0.5)
y1 <- x*rnorm(300,0.1,0.1)
study <- rep(c("a","b","c"),each = 100)
weight.var <-  rep(c(0.5,2,4),each = 100)
weight.var1 <-  rep(c(0.1,.2,.15),each = 100)
library(lme4)
dataset <- data.frame(x,y,y1,study,weight.var,weight.var1)
resp1 <- c("y","y1")
weight.opt <- c("weight.var","weight.var1")
for(i in 1:2){
  lmer(as.formula(paste(resp1[i],"~x+(1|study)")),weights = weight.opt[i],data = dataset)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you're asking; does `weights = dataset[[weight.opt[i]]]` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
res_list <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
    res_list[[i]] <- lmer(as.formula(paste(resp1[i],"~x+(1|study)")),
         weights = dataset[[weight.opt[i]]],data = dataset)
}
```